# How would I check for a proper custom input of mm/dd/yyyy in actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

I have a DataField with `editable="true"` and format mm/dd/yyyy. Then lets say user typed in month `mm` section `13` which is not correct. How can I validate it as well as `dd` section and `yyyy` section and show a pop up when it's incorrect?

Here is what happening when `apply` button was clicked:

```
var newDate:Date = dfDate.selectedDate;
var month:String = (newDate.month + 1) < 10 ? "0" + (newDate.month + 1).toString() : (newDate.month + 1).toString();
var date:String = newDate.date < 10 ? "0" + newDate.date.toString() : newDate.date.toString();
var year:Number = newDate.getFullYear();
var dateString:String = month + "/" + date + "/" + year;
```

Button section:

```
<mx:FormItem id="itemDate">
    <mx:DateField id="dfDate" yearNavigationEnabled="true" editable="true"/>
</mx:FormItem>
```

Comment: you can write logic in FocusOut event.

Comment: okay will try, but do you know is there a more universal way to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate, take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5009106/flex-datefield-validate-date-with-editable-true

Comment: Thank you guys, actually I know an answer already, do you know how can I answer my own question if I did not checked a check box "Answer your own question"?

Comment: In the focusout event you can check  if the dfDate.selectedDate is null, then the date is not valid. This is a simple check for its validity.

Comment: There should be a button for "Answer your question" at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use just a simple regular expression

```
var customRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp(/(0[1-9]|1[012])[\/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](19|20)\d\d/);
```

And then use `.test` function along with some formatting stuff

```
var fmt:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
fmt.formatString = "MM/DD/YYYY";

if(!customRegExp.test(fmt.format(dfDate.selectedDate)))
{
    Alert.show("Please input date in format MM/DD/YYYY");
    enableForm(true);
}
```

Worked for me just fine and I think will work for others as well!

Here is code all together:

```
var customRegExp:RegExp = new RegExp(/(0[1-9]|1[012])[\/](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[\/](19|20)\d\d/);

var fmt:DateFormatter = new DateFormatter();
fmt.formatString = "MM/DD/YYYY";

if(!customRegExp.test(fmt.format(dfDate.selectedDate)))
{
    Alert.show("Please input date in format MM/DD/YYYY");
    enableForm(true);
}
```